# Why does my goblin only choose a walk direction once?

Tags: javascript, sprites, html-canvas

I'm working on a simpe 2d canvas game that has a small goblin sprite who I want to get pathing around the screen.

What I originally tried was a random roll that would choose a direction, the goblin would walk that direction. It didnt work effectively, he sort of wobbled in one spot.

Here's my current apporach but he only runs in a rundom direction and doesnt change. What am I doing wrong?

Here's all the relevant code to the goblin object and movement.

```
    var goblin = {
            speed: 100,
            pos: [0, 0],
            dir: 1,
            changeDir: true,
            stepCount: 0,
            stepTotal: 0,
            sprite: new Sprite(
                                goblinImage, 
                                [0,0], 
                                [30,45], 
                                6, 
                                [0,1,2,3,2,1],
                                true)
    };


    function getNewDir(){
            goblin.dir = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
    };

    function checkGoblinMovement(){
        if(goblin.changeDir){
            goblin.changeDir = false;
            goblin.stepCount = 0;
            goblin.stepTotal = Math.floor(Math.random*650)+1;
            getNewDir();
        }
        else
         {
           if(goblin.stepCount === goblin.stepTotal){
                 goblin.changeDir = true;
         }
       }
    };

    function update(delta){

        healthCheck();

        if(isGameOver){
            gameOver();
        }
        if(!isGameOver){
        updateCharLevel();  
        keyboardInput(delta);   

        moveGoblin(delta);
        checkGoblinMovement();  

        goblin.sprite.update(delta);

        //update sprites
        if(mainChar.kills!=0 && bloodReady){
            for(var i=0; i<bloodArray.length; i++){
                    bloodArray[i].sprite.update(delta);
         }
        }

        //collision detection   
        if(collision(mainChar, goblin))
            {
               combatOutcome(combatEvent());
               combatCleanup();
            }
            }
        };

    function main(){
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = (now - then)/1000;  
        if(!isGameOver){
        update(delta);
        }
        draw();
        then = now;
    };

function moveGoblin(delta){

    goblin.stepCount++;

    if(goblin.dir === 1){
      goblin.pos[1]  -= goblin.speed * delta* 2;        
        if(goblin.pos[1] <= 85){
            goblin.pos[1] = 86;
          }
    }

    if(goblin.dir === 2){
        goblin.pos[1]  += goblin.speed * delta;     
        if(goblin.pos[1] > 530){
            goblin.pos[1] = 531;
          }
    }

    if(goblin.dir === 3){
      goblin.pos[0]  -= goblin.speed * delta;       
        if(goblin.pos[0] < 0){
            goblin.pos[0] = 1;
          }
    }

    if(goblin.dir === 4){
      goblin.pos[0]  += goblin.speed * delta* 2;        
        if(goblin.pos[0] > 570){
            goblin.pos[0] = 571;
          }
    }

};
```

Comment: goblin.stepTotal = Math.floor(Math.random*650)+1; has no () after Math.random ... I don't know javascript but if its anything like other languages this tries to get the random variable or property from the Math struct. I highly doubt this gets a random number like you want. That or you copied it wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your goblin is initialized in a state such that `changeDir` is true. Thus, the first time you call `checkGoblinMovement` you will assign a new direction and step total to the goblin.

The next time the goblin will change direction is when the current step count equals the step total. This will never occur, because you do not appear to ever increment `stepCount` anywhere. You probably want to do this once per loop.

Note that this is a problem you could easily solve yourself by mastering your debugger and stepping through the code line by line. You'd see that every time you check for the step count to equal the step total, you have the same step count as last time.

You could also achieve a solution by analyzing your logic backwards: you know the problem state is that the goblin doesn't ever change direction after the first time. So look at the conditions in your code that cause the goblin to change direction, and work backwards from there figuring out what causes each of those bits of code to execute and why they might not.

Comment: Hey Josh, thank you for your reply.

I actually left out my movement function in the question where this increment happens. I've appended it to the above!

Comment: Then consider doing what I suggested in the second half of my answer and stepping through the code in a debugger.